# Build PNaCl for use in chromium embedded framework

Tags: chromium-embedded, google-nativeclient, gyp

I am trying to build PNaCl for use in CEF. I have managed to build the PPAPI examples as defined [here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10509):

```
1. Build CEF3/Chromium from source code as described at https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembed ... ndBuilding.
2. Edit C:\chromium\src\build\some.gyp, add '../ppapi/ppapi_internal.gyp:ppapi_example_paint_manager' in the 'dependencies' section.
3. Run `gclient runhooks` from the chromium src directory to update the build files.
4. Open C:\chromium\src\build\some.sln (on equivalent on other platforms) and build the ppapi_example_paint_manager target to create ppapi_example_paint_manager.dll.
```

How do i configure gyp for building a PNaCL/NaCl plugin that i can load into CEF?

Answer (score 0):

Loading a NaCl or PNaCl plugin into CEF will be no different than loading it into Chrome. As such, you can use the standard build tools for building Native Client plugins. Start with the [Native Client SDK](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/sdk/download), and try building the demos and examples there.

You won't typically use gyp for building PNaCl/NaCl plugins. Using gyp is difficult because it requires manually setting up the Native Client toolchains as the build target. The Native Client SDK includes a set of Makefiles that do this for you automatically.

You may also want to take a look at [naclports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/). This repository has ports of many open-source libraries to Native Client, which may help you in porting your application.